# Overriding AppConfig.ready()

Tags: django

Trying to catch the basics of Django. Namely how Applications work.
The docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#methods

And in the code of the class AppConfig we can read:

```
def ready(self):
    """
    Override this method in subclasses to run code when Django starts.
    """
```

Well, this is my example:

**my_app/apps.py**

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'

    def ready(self):
        print('My app')
```

I just want to make the ready method work. That is, when Django finds my_app, let it run the ready method.

The app is registered in INSTALLED_APPS.

I execute 'python manage.py runserver'. And nothing is printed.

If I place a breakpoint inside the ready method, the debugger don't stop there.

Could you help me: what is my mistake in understanding here. Thank you in advance.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
]
```

And I created a view

**my_app/views.py**

```
def index(request):
    print('Print index')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', my_app_views.index, name='home')
]
```

Well, the view is working. This means that the application is registered.

Comment: Please show the code from settings where you register the app in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Please, see the edited post.

Comment: @Michael does it work for you ? Because I'm trying to do same thing and I'm using accepted answer and it doesn't work

Comment: @KyluAce Yes it functions properly.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You need to do one of two things. Either explicitly say which `AppConfig` you want in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig'
]
```

Or, define a `default_app_config` in the `__init__.py` of your app:

```
# my_app/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

(and leave `INSTALLED_APPS` as-is).

As it is currently Django can't find any `AppConfig` for the app and just assumes there isn't one. So your views etc. will work, but the `ready()` method will never get called.

Here's the [relevant section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#configuring-applications).

**Edit**: as of Django 3.2, specifying a `default_app_config` is no longer necessary, [and is in fact deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/#what-s-new-in-django-3-2) - so this answer is redundant for anyone using Django 3.2 or later.

Comment: When i try adding the line to `my_app/__init__.py`, it doesn't end up calling `ready()` function. It works just fine using the `INSTALLED_APPS` route. Any idea why that wouldn't be called?

Comment: It gives me django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. error

Comment: Note that you need to add `--noreload` param when runserver to skip call ready() method twice.

Comment: @ParikshitChalke I had the same problem. This is caused by circular imports. Just move whatever you're importing within `ready()` and not outside of it and it'll work.

Comment: @watersnake: In my case I had typo in default_app_config: ...AppConfig instead of proper ...<ChildConfig>.

Comment: I am getting an exception ImportError: No module named core.apps
where core is the my app directory
and inside core.__init__.py 
I added default_app_config = 'core.apps.CoreConfig'