# Django signals not working for my directory structure

Tags: django, django-signals

I am trying to implement signals for my app and my directory structure looks like this

```
- src
    - utility_apps
        __init__.py
        - posts
            - migrations
            - static
            - templates
            admin.py
            views.py
            apps.py
            signals.py
            models.py
            __init__.py
            ......

    static
    manage.py
    ......
```

Here `posts` is my app and the `signals.py` is inside its folder, But my signals aren't working. 
I have defined my signal code as -

```
from .models import Post
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def give_group_owner_permission(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print("coming to signal")
    if created:
        print("created")
```

But it doesn't work. In my `apps.py` I have changed the ready function as

```
class Post(AppConfig):
    name = 'post'

    def ready(self):
        import utility_apps.posts.signals
```

I have even tried importing `posts.signal` in the ready function. What I am doing wrong here, please help

My installed apps look like below

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'utility_apps.posts',
    'mainapp',
     .....
]
```

Comment: Can you should us your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: not a proper answer but why using a signal for something that could be in your post model save???

Comment: @ShahrukhMohammad please see [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429726/overriding-appconfig-ready/37430196#37430196) - that might fix your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding AppConfig.ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429726/overriding-appconfig-ready)

Comment: @ShahrukhMohammad where is your model.py?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers using signals was more appropriate here, thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @solarissmoke thanks a lot, the solution worked for me with a slight change

Comment: @BenyaminJafari models.py is at the same directory level as signals.py

Comment: @ShahrukhMohammad hmm, So add this (models.py) in your directory structure in your question, I had confused.

Comment: @ShahrukhMohammad please put on models.py snipped code.

Comment: I have edited the question, apologies for causing a confusion, I have got my solution, which I have posted. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The following solution worked for me.

The first change which I had to make was put a `default_app_config` value in my `__init__.py` file of my `posts` app as

```
default_app_config = 'utility_apps.posts.apps.PostsConfig'
```

And then I had to change `PostsConfig` class as

```
class PostsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'utility_apps.posts'

    def ready(self):
        import utility_apps.posts.signals
```

Basically I had to change two things -

1. The name which was set to `posts` by default
2. Change the ready function and import my signals in it

It worked for me.
Alternatively, I could have also included my PostsConfig in my installed app.