# Pre_delete signal does not work in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am working with signals in Django, specifically with the `pre_delete` signal, code:

`signals.py` file:

```
def delete_unnecessary_image(sender, instance, using):
    print('holaaaa')
    instance.image.delete(save = False)
```

`apps.py` file (here I register the receivers in the `ready()` method):

```
def ready(self):
    from .signals import delete_unnecessary_image
    from .models import Course
    pre_delete.connect(delete_unnecessary_image, sender = Course)
```

My `INSTALLED_APPS` and configuration in my `settings.py`:

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    ....
]

MY_APPS = [
    'core',
    'courses',
    'instructor'
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + MY_APPS
```

The problem is that it doesn't work, it doesn't eliminate the image of the `Course` model, and I don't know why. Any solution?

Comment: Please show us your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: What type of field is `image` on the `Course` model? What does `save=False` mean in the call to `instance.image.delete(save=False)`?

Comment: the `save=False` means that it will not save the file or image when removing the value from the field. and in the model the `image` field is a `ImageField`.

Comment: @solarissmoke I already updated my answer showing my `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: I think you're probably running into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429726/overriding-appconfig-ready/37430196#37430196 . Once you fix that, you will get another error which is that `save` is an invalid kwarg for `delete()` - it doesn't make sense to pass `save=False` here.

Comment: In the django documentation it says that if it is necessary to specify the `save=False` for the file to be deleted, check it out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete

Comment: My problem is already solved thanks! by the way I did not get error for the `save=False`

Comment: where should i but the `save=False`